# jQuery show one next sibling at a time on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show hidden rows one at a time on button click, but they all show at once since they have class "row" - the 1st row is shown by default and the rest are hidden

I can't use Id selectors since it's server side and dynamic, so how can I only show the immediate next row/sibling on each click until there are none left? I could append a counter to each row class but that wouldn't help when trying to select the next row in jQuery with that counter

This is what I have which shows all rows on one click

```
<script>
 $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $('.container .row').next('.row:hidden').slideDown();
 });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <!-- 1st row not hidden by default -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
</div>
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: look into jQueries `.index()` and `.eq()` You can find the index number with `.index()` and you can select the specific row with `.eq()`.  You may also want to look into `.next()`

Comment: include a fiddle (or other demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.container .row:visible').last().next('.row:hidden').slideDown();
```

If all you're doing is showing them in a sequential order, then you don't need to track which are active.  You can simply use the visibility to always choose the last.

All you do is add the `:visible` to the row selection, to find all visible rows; then use the `last()` method to only reference the last of that stack.  This allows `next()` to be called for only one element (the last one), and not all the rows in the container.

To simplify this even more (and call fewer methods), you could choose to only select the first hidden row: `$('.container .row:hidden:first').slideDown();` or `$('.container .row:hidden').first().slideDown();`

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhs0uxo4/)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you add the class "selected" to the first row than you could do this:

```
<script>
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $('.container .row.selected')
      .removeClass('selected')
      .hide()
      .next()
      .addClass('selected')
      .slideDown();
  );
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row selected">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
</div>
```

Comment: I would upvote this, if you need to know the active slide.  There may be more than one visible (like three slides), but want to highlight the selected/active one.  For something like that, hidden/visibility may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterating through the collection to display the correct one. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjqb6m83/

```
var i = 0; 
var collection = $(".row");

$(".myButton").click(function() {    
    $(collection).css('display', 'none');
    $(collection[i]).slideDown();
    i++
    i = i % collection.length;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:nth-child()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 1;
    $(".myButton").click(function() {
        counter++;
        $('.container .row').hide();
        $('.container .row:nth-child(' + counter + ')').slideDown();
    });
});
```

```css
.row {
    display:none;
}
.row:nth-child(1) {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton">My Button</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">row 1</div>
    <div class="row">row 2</div>
    <div class="row">row 3</div>
    <div class="row">row 4</div>
    <div class="row">row 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of another **jQuery-pseudo-selector [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

```
$(".myButton").click(function() {
    $('.container .row:hidden:first').slideDown()
 });
```

and dont forget to **close your divs**! Look at https://jsfiddle.net/kswmktce/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. This one shows just one at a time, and starts over when finished.

```js
$(".myButton").click(function() {
  $(".row:visible").next().slideDown();
  $(".row:visible").first().hide();

  if (!$(".row:visible").length)
    $(".row").first().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton">Click ME</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">a</div>
  <div class="row">b</div>
  <div class="row">c</div>
  <div class="row">d</div>
  <div class="row">e</div>
</div>
```